# How does DllImport identify the newest .dll-Version?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dllimport

I have a winforms application and can call an external method located in a third-party-dll successfully. This dll-file is located anywhere on my machine.

```
[DllImport("ext.dll")]
public static extern int Print(string cmd);
```

Yesterday i get a batch from the company developing that ext.dll because of an internal bug located in the Print-Method. The batch contains a bug-free version of ext.dll.

Now my question is: How does DllImport find this new bug-free version located anywhere on my machine and use it instead of the old one? 
Additional Information: I use DllImport because i can not add the dll-file via "Add Reference" in VS.

Comment: It does not, it uses a search algorithm to find the dll and will load the first one it finds.

Comment: There is no Santa Claus, aggressively delete buggy versions so DLL Hell cannot byte you.

Answer (score 6):

The p/invoke marshaller calls `LoadLibrary` (or `LoadLibraryEx`) passing the file name that you specify in the `DllImport` attribute. This means that the system searches for the DLL using the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). The documentation I linked to has all the gory details. Essentially the system searches in a number of pre-defined locations and the first location that it encounters which contains a file of the specified name is used.

So, on to your specific question:

> How does DllImport find this new bug-free version located anywhere on my machine and use it instead of the old one?

It doesn't. It uses the Dynamic-Link Library Search Order. If that happens to locate the latest version of the DLL, then that's what gets loaded. If an older version of the DLL comes up first in the search, then that older version will be loaded.